# How to install TeXLive on Linux in user directory

Tags: texlive, installing, linux

As per the title, I was wondering how to install *texlive-full* in a user's home directory on a Linux machine (in my case, running Debian 9).

This would be very useful as a full texlive installation takes quite a lot of space (up to 6GB), and my root partition is pretty limited. Also, since it's a personal computer, I wouldn't need to share the installation with any other users.

I searched but only found what I think is a way to make a user-install of custom packages only (see e.g. [1]).

Thank you very much in advance.

[1] https://wiki.debian.org/Latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the best way is to install upstream TeX Live, in particular the (default) scheme-full (which corresponds to the Debian package texlive-full). Installation of TeX Live is straight-forward as described [here](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). After that you should install a so called equivs package that tells the Debian packaging manager (apt) that you have a locally installed TeX Live available, see [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html).